# React i18next Server Side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering, i18next

I have express as a backend and React as a front-end.

When using React i18next with server-side rendering server-side (express) ReactDOMServer.renderToString returns generated HTML, however instead of the actual translated strings it has keys. Is that the intended behavior? Can the translation be done on the server side?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your i18next config probably not configured to work on the server side. check this out https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/serverside-rendering

Comment: I guess my question is like follows. Should server side return already translated texts or just preloaded store and language?

Comment: It depends, usually when u do ssr version of your app it is for seo  purposes, therefore you should return a translated text which search engines will understand